# "End of Table" Message at the very first blank column of the table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying the get the values from source sheet `INPUT!G19` to `G45`.

Destination sheet is `J1604` onwards, when source sheet ends with blank.

I am trying to fill the text "End of the table"

I have a formula in `J1604`:  `IF(G19="",""G19)`

I tried these formulas, but I could not attain. Please help.

```
=LET(lst,FILTER(P$4:P$100,P$4:P$100<>""),num,COUNTA(lst),indx,ROW()/4,
          IF(indx<=num,INDEX(lst,indx,1),IF(indx=num+1,"End of list","")))=
```

and

```
=IF(COUNTIF($J$1603:$J1603,"End of List")>0,"",IFERROR(INDEX($G$19:$G$45,SMALL(IF($G$19:$G$45<>"",ROW($G$19:$G$45),""),ROWS($J$1604:$J$1604))-ROW($J$1603)),"End of List"))
```

Comment: In the first formula why are you referring to `P4:P100` instead of `INPUT!G19 to G45`?

Comment: sorry it should refer INPUT!G19:INPUT!G45, - it works if it is P4:P100, But actually it must be refer Input sheet G coloumn. Thanks

Comment: Yes when you use `INPUT!G19:G45` why it is not working what error do you get

Comment: im  getting only blank rows as result

Comment: it would be great time help if you solved

Comment: Refer screenshot i have posted in answer, instead of using `ROW()/4` use as I have shown that will work.

Comment: First error I notice: IF(G19="",""G19) should be IF(G19="","",G19)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way, refer i have specifically used cell <kbd>A4</kbd> for the variable <kbd>c</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>J1604</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,TOCOL(INPUT!G:G,1),
     b,ROWS(a),
     c,ROW(A4)/4,
     IFS(c<=b,INDEX(a,c,1),c=b+1,"End of list"))
```

---

As per OP's comment

> *thanks, can you help if it is not merged cell I know that formula
> which i tried its merged cells but this time Not merged.*

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>J1604</kbd>

```
=VSTACK(TOCOL(INPUT!G:G,1),"End of list")
```

---

Or,

```
=VSTACK(TOCOL(INPUT!G19:G45,1),"End of list")
```

---

As per OP

> *=VSTACK(TOCOL(INPUT!G19:G45,1),"End of list") Resulted J1604= #NAME? Please Guide. Microsoft Office Standard 2021*

[image]

```
=LET(
     a, FILTER(INPUT!G19:G45,INPUT!G19:G45<>""),
     b, SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)+1),
     IFERROR(INDEX(a,b),"End of list"))
```

---

Workbook can be downloaded from **[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cj3zpOidRdSLiH5Xk?e=hHhsHn)** <-- Click !

---

Comment: thanks, can you help if it is not merged cell 
I know that formula which i tried  its  merged cells but this time Not merged.

Comment: @HummBird Sure thing, updated now

Comment: thanks for continue help, 
INPUT!G:G - I have other data before G19 so my referece start from G19 only.

Comment: @HummBird then change this part to `TOCOL(INPUT!G:G,1)` to `TOCOL(INPUT!G19:G45,1)`

Comment: =VSTACK(TOCOL(INPUT!G19:G45,1),"End of list")

Resulted J1604= #NAME?
Please Guide

Comment: @HummBird what is your excel version?

Comment: Microsoft Office Standard 2021

Comment: sorry, i thought it will work G19:G45 - but no luck.

Comment: Any other approch, will be much help full, please

Comment: @HummBird updated

Comment: oh no... I am getting error #SPILL!

Comment: that could be many reasons first of all you need to clear the cells below the formula, there may be something also if you are using `Structured Tables` this wont work

Comment: I once again rechecked and cleared the  till end of that last footer coloumn but still the same #SPILL error. Can we limit the cell range to J1604 :J1634
thanks for being with me

Comment: Yes, as you wish, can you post the excel file ? let me see what is the struggle you are facing in. Also formula will spill, you dont have to fill down

Comment: I amsearching how to send my workbook

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255471/discussion-between-hummbird-and-mayukh-bhattacharya).